# How can I delete sharing links using Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I have created a flow with the following steps:

1. Get all document sets in a library
2. For each document set (all steps using Send an HTTP Request to SharePoint)

   - Reset Role inheritance
   - Break Role inheritance  `breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)`
   - Set new permissions

This flow works mostly as expected. The permissions are set correctly, but if i look at a document inside the document set that has been shared previously, there are remnants of the sharing link which I would prefer wasn't there, with a message stating "This link is broken. Delete it and share the item again"

[image: Text]

**Question:** Is there a way to remove all potential sharing links for documents inside a document set as part of the flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can choose to terminate the sharing of this file.

Make a flow on a schedule that is daily

Get the items

If StopSharingDate = Today

Execute StopSharing Action

[image]

Comment: I had tried using the Stop sharing an item or a file action initially, but it was failing with an invalid JSON error for some reason. It appears to be working now.